# How to sum of range within a Data frame by Passing the Column Names into a Variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to sum the values in a range. Something similar to values within a row and a particular range.

The catch is to pass the range which I want to add by passing them as column headers. I am able to add it by mentioning the column numbers but I am looking for another solution.

The data I am working with is given below:

```
structure(list(Type = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "B"), `Row Labels` = c("X6", 
"X7", "X8", "X9", "X11", "X12"), `2022-11-07` = c(25, 50, 75, 
100, 25, 50), `2022-11-14` = c(25, 50, 75, 100, 25, 50), `2022-11-21` = c(25, 
50, 75, 100, 50, 100), `2022-11-28` = c(25, 50, 75, 100, 75, 
150), `2022-12-05` = c(40, 50, 75, 100, 125, 250), `2022-12-12` = c(40, 
50, 75, 100, 200, 400), `2022-12-19` = c(40, 50, 75, 100, 325, 
650), `2022-12-26` = c(40, 50, 75, 100, 525, 1050), `2023-01-02` = c(100, 
110, 120, 130, 850, 1700), `2023-01-09` = c(100, 110, 120, 130, 
1375, 2750), `2023-01-16` = c(100, 110, 120, 130, 2225, 4450), 
    `2023-01-23` = c(100, 110, 120, 130, 3600, 7200), `2023-01-30` = c(100, 
    110, 120, 130, 5825, 11650)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

The code I wrote for this is:

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

Book1 <- read_excel("C:/X/X/X- X/X/Book1.xlsx",sheet = "Sheet4")

Last_Date <- tail(colnames(Book1),1)
First_Date <- head(colnames(Book1),3)[3]

Book1$Sum <- rowSums(Book1[c,(any_of(First_Date):any_of(Last_Date))])
```

I cant seem to resolve the error in this line. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may select range of columns using `select` -

```
library(dplyr)

Book1 <- Book1 %>% mutate(Sum = rowSums(select(., `2022-11-07`:`2023-01-30`)))
Book1
```

---

If you have to use `First_Date` and `Last_Date` variable to select the range then you can use `match` to get corresponding column indices and create a range of columns to subset.

```
cols <- colnames(Book1)
Book1$Sum <- rowSums(Book1[match(First_Date, cols):match(Last_Date, cols)])
```

Comment: The expectation is to pass it through a variable and not to mention the column names in the statement. Can you please help me out.

Comment: @Ronah Shah Can you tell me if this can be done using Pipe function?